# For a series, can you always find a subseries whose sum is smaller in magnitude?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let's say you got a series $a_n$, such that $\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n=L>0$. For any $0 \lt K \le L$, can you always find a subsequence $b_n$ of $a_n$, such that $\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_n=K$? If not always, when can you?

(Inspired by [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647409/can-an-infinite-sum-of-irrational-numbers-be-rational#comment3359992_1647409).)

Comment: Are we assuming that $\sum a_n$ converges?

Comment: If $\sum_nx_n$ converges but $\sum_n|x_n|$ does not, then for any $r$ there is an infinite subsequence summing to $r$.

Comment: @user254665 Do you have a citation for that? That sounds cool!

Comment: I recall it is in the book Infinite Sequences And Series by Bromwich. Let $P=\{n :x_n>0\}=\{f(n):n\in N\}.\; M=\{n:x_n<0\}=\{g(n):n\in N\}$ where $f,g$ are strictly increasing. Neither of $\sum_{n\in P}x_n, \;\sum_{n\in M}x_n\}$ converges but $x_{f(n)}$ and $x_{g(n)}$ go to $0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Take a finite set $A_1$ of consecutive terms of $A=\{x_{f(n)}:n\in N\}$  until their sum  $S_1$ exceeds $r.$ Then take consecutive terms of  $B=\{x_{g(n)}:n\in N\}$  of higher subscript than those in $A_1$, until their sum  $S_2$ satisfies $S_1+S_2<r.$ Then select from $A$ until....

Comment: That's the (Levy-)Steinitz (derangement) theorem. Actually the first known formulation was by Grassmann some 50-60 years earlier, in the context of vector valued series.

Comment: Now that I re-thought it, the statement in Bromwich was that we could re-arrange the whole series to get a sum of any value. But here we are asked for a subsequence. I'm not at all familiar with the history of it.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot always do it. Look for example at the series $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{10^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

For large $L$, take $a_0 = L - 1$ and $a_n = 2^{-n}$ for $n \geq 1$. Then for any subset $I\subset \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$, the sum $s = \sum_{n\in I} a_n$ has $s \geq L -1$ if $0\in I$ and $s\leq 1$ otherwise.