# Can an infinite sum of non-computable numbers be computable, such that all finite sums of subsets of terms are non-computable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, computability

**Background**

In the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647409/can-an-infinite-sum-of-irrational-numbers-be-rational), User1 asks whether an infinite sum of irrational numbers can be rational. Multiple answers<sup>1</sup> indicate the answer to this question is 'yes'. For instance, Rasmus Erlemann [notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1647422/53283) that

$$\tan \frac{\pi}4=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n+2}(2^{2n+2}-1)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)^{2n+1}=1, $$ by the Maclaurin series of $\tan(\cdot)$.

**The Question**

This question is asked in a similar spirit. I wonder whether there are any infinite series consisting solely of non-computable terms, that amount to a computable number. Examples of such non-computable numbers can found [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462790/are-there-any-examples-of-non-computable-real-numbers?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). They include [Chaitin's constants](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChaitinsConstant.html).

To make the question more precise, define $$ C = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_{k} . $$  Here, all $u_{k}$ are non-computable numbers. I am looking for explicit examples of infinite series such that $C$ is a computable number, and all $u_{k}$ are both positive and linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Added**

Although user TonyK answers my initial question correctly, I would like to add another restriction to make the question more interesting. I furthermore require that every sum of a finite subset of summands of the infinite series is also non-computable. This makes TonyK's example unworkable, since, for instance, the sum of the first two terms is computable: $$ \alpha u_{1} + (1-\alpha)u_{1} = u_{1}, $$ where $\alpha$ is non-computable and $u_{1}$ is a positive computable term.

---

<sup>**Notes**</sup>

<sup>[1] If you're interested in such series, I encourage you to also take a look at my [recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4860962/53283). It involves a class of representations of numbers, called *rational zeta series*, that offers a fruitful way to approach this problem. For instance, the answer includes the series identity $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \zeta(2n)-1 \right] = \frac{3}{4} . $$</sup>

Comment: Isn't such a manipulation enough to show theoretically? If we have infinitely many $u_i$'s that are both positive and linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then let's say, that they sum to an uncomputable sum:  
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} u_{i}=U$$
What I think is true but it's not a proof, that the following is true, and the final result also has the required properties:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{C* u_{i}}{C}=U$$
$$\frac{1}{C} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} C* u_{i}=U$$
$$\frac{1}{U} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} C* u_{i}=C$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{C* u_{i}}{U}=C$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$ be an uncomputable number, and let $\sum u_k$ be any convergent series of positive computable terms linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$. Then the series $$\alpha u_1+(1-\alpha)u_1+\alpha u_2+(1-\alpha)u_2+\cdots$$
satisfies your conditions (because any linear dependency over $\Bbb Q$ would give us a way to compute the uncomputable $\alpha$).

You asked for an explicit example, so take for instance $u_k=p_k^{-3/2}$, where $p^k$ is the $p$th prime.

Comment: Hmmm, although this answer is probably correct, it somewhat feels like a trick. I'd prefer an answer in which the terms don't cancel out the non-computable numbers. I'm not sure, however, how this restriction ought to be incorporated within the question. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I can't read your mind, Max!

Comment: I've added a restriction. I hope you don't take offence at this -- I'm grateful for the effort you've put in your answer, and for the opportunity it has provided to formulate a more focussed question.

Comment: @MaxMuller It doesn't really matter whether TonyK takes offence, it's against site norms to change a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. When you have a question that allowed an answer you didn't expect, the thing to do would be to post a new question and leave your original one (unless no one's posted an answer yet). Also, based on the title alone I came to give a worse version of TonyK's answer so if you *are* going to leave this question changed, it would be nice to at least change the title accordingly.